# Deleted Ubuntu partition in Windows Disk Manager

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm a rookie and complete noob in Linux. My Ubuntu was working just fine, grub waiting for my choices without a timer, tor installed, etc.

This morning, for no apparent reason, I entered Windows Disk Manager and saw an unused partition of 18Gb in my 250Gb SSD and deleted my Ubuntu operating system partition unconsciously.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 17 because the system couldn't boot and stayed in grub recover. But I think data from my old Ubuntu installation is still there in partition 5. Can I recover that installation?

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type    
/dev/sda1            2048    409599    407552  199M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda2          409600 449289776 448880177  214G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda3       449290238 488396799  39106562 18,7G  5 Extended    
/dev/sda5  *    471824384 488396799  16572416  7,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris    
/dev/sda6       449290240 471824383  22534144 10,8G 83 Linux
```

[image: view of the drive in GNOME Disks]

I believe now that all data is lost as explained in [this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1555656). This is now a swap partition. So, if it is lost can I delete the swap partition and expand `/dev/sda6`?

**Update:** Thanks to you all. After expanding partitions to restore my 20gb to Ubuntu I lost grub again, but with grub rescue tutorial I restored it and now all is working again:

[image: GNOME Disks screenshot again]

Comment: If you had not re-installed, you may have been able to fully recover with testdisk. Re-install overwrote some or most of old data, but Linux is not like Windows that tries to keep data at beginning of drive. Data is randomly written throughout drive. So photorec may recover some data.But you must stop using drive as it is then overwriting more data,  and only use live installer. Also grub does not use boot flag. Windows requires boot flag. So move boot flag back to sda1.

Answer (score 1):

When you just delete a partition from a partition utility, you can recover that partition and content thanks to testdisk. As soon as you make new partition and override the hard drive, all content is lost and written over. The only way left is using tools like photorec to make empty space scan, useful to recover photo, but I have some doubts that it's working fine on SSD drives.

Comment: Exactly. Using testdisk to recover a partition deleted using the Windows Disk Management tool is basically automatic. Just analyze the target disk, make sure the partition is showing there and write the partition table back to the disk. After finishing the process, just reboot the computer and you will be able to use grub to select Ubuntu and log in there normally.